# Reset the NODATA to negative value error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, nodata

I have a requirement for converting NODATA to value -3 with my floating point data. I have tried to reset NODATA by using Raster Calculator with the formula of `Con(IsNull("tif"),-3,"tif")`. But when I check the properties it seems like nothing change. The NODATA is still an extremely small value.

[image]

So I would like to ask two question:

1. If this command useful for converting NODATA to negative values?
2. If I reset the NODATA value when export raster data, does it have the same meaning?

[image]

[image]

(NODATA seems to be changed successfully when I reset in export window)

Comment: Your use of `Con(IsNull("tif"),-3,"tif")` is perfectly valid, I just don't believe the raster calculator updates what is NODATA. If you clicked in a no data cell you will see that it has indeed taken on -3 value. Simply follow @Padmanabha answer to correct this bug.

Comment: @Hornbydd Thank you so much for your reply. I'll try to fixed this bug by using the  below suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The NoData value can be edited by computing it from the raster dataset properties. It will permanently change the value and while exporting it will remain the same.

1. In the ArcCatalog or the Catalog window, right-click the raster dataset and click Properties

[image]

2. On the General tab, under Raster Information is the NoData Value. Click the Edit button.

[image]

3. Click the column next to the band name to edit the NoData Value and Click Ok.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply and giving me so many details. I'm curious if this method can really change the original data, rather than the results presented? I mean I've tried resetting NODATA when exporting raster data, and it seems to have the same result, but it shows an error in the model I'm running. (BTW my NODATA only appears at the boundary of the layer, not within the attribute table.) 
Looking forward to any replies and thanks in advance.
Jen